# Subtraction of two arrays with incremental indexes of the other array to a maximum limit

Tags: ruby

I have lots of math to do on lots of data but it's all based on a few base templates. So instead of say, when doing math between 2 arrays I do this:

```
results = [a[0]-b[1],a[1]-b[2],a[2]-b[3]]
```

I want to instead just put the base template: a[0]-b[1] and make it automatically fill say 50 places in the results array. So I don't always have to manually type it.

What would be the ways to do that? And would a good way be to create 1 method that does this automatically. And I just tell it the math and it fills out an array?

I have no clue, I'm really new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom

```
  a = [2,3,4..............,1000]
  b = [1,2,3,4,.............900]

  class Array
   def self.calculate_difference(arr1,arr2,limit)
    begin
     result ||= Array.new
     limit.send(:times) {|index| result << arr1[index]-arr2[index+=1]} 
     result
   rescue
    raise "Index/Limit Error"
   end
  end
 end
```

Call by:

```
Array.calculate_difference(a,b,50)
```

Comment: Hmm I'm getting all kinds of errors using that. Obviously I fixed the arrays first. But I still get "undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

Comment: Thank you very much! Though I had to put .to_f to make it work. And that was probably part of the problem with your earlier code as well. I've had this problem before where I thought it would easily recognize the array as the correct data type but it doesn't seem to do it. I'm not sure if its normal or not, I'm on windows.

Comment: It had the same problem being not able to calculate the arrays together.

Comment: whr did u put to_f? and where is it not recognizing the data type.. can u tell me

Comment: arr1[index].to_i-arr2[index+=1].to_i} - That's the only place I've tried it and it made it work. This time I put to_i just because I guess it's more standard.

Comment: for me when i tested it worked without it.. neways if the solution helped you. do vote up

Comment: Yes I did thanks! This is the best solution for me. With it I can also make the math itself entered when using the method/class. This way I can use that one code base to create everything I need. Thank you very much! - Basically your answer opened up the solution on how to do all of this.

Comment: Why `limit.send(:times)`instead of `limit.times`?

Comment: @steenslag since the person who raised the question is new to ruby programming I wanted to give a idea of what metaprogramming can do and out of curiosity if he checks the send method documentation so will be a add on to him. We can also use `limit.times`

Answer (score 4):

```
a = [2,3,4]
b = [1,2,3,4]

results = a.zip(b.drop(1)).take(50).map { |v,w| v - w }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain it a little bit for me? How would I get the intended results from that? This calculates a0 with b0, which is another calculation I want to do. However what about a0 - b1? And then the last thing is I absolutely don't want it to calculate the whole arrays together, only 50 spots or so. Whatever I pick.